# relation "comparison_bundle" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comparison_bundle"

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

It's a new database that I have just created with Postgresql.

When I go to the admin page everythin works fine except when I try to go to the "Bundle" model.

Here is the model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    info = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Bundle(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    info = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=4, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Company, Bundle

class BundleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets= [
        ('Bundles info', {'fields':['title', 'packet', 'info', 'price']}),
    ]
```

And this is what i get:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  584.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  204.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1486.                 self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in __init__
  110.         self.get_results(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in get_results
  219.         result_count = paginator.count
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in _get_count
  72.                 self._count = self.object_list.count()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in count
  338.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_count
  424.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using=using)[None]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_aggregation
  390.         result = query.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(SINGLE)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  786.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/comparison/bundle/
Exception Value: relation "comparison_bundle" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comparison_bundle"
```

In the terminal I get this error:

```
[01/Dec/2014 13:45:43] "GET /admin/comparison/bundle/ HTTP/1.1" 500 211501
```

Could this be because I Created a new database and replaced the old database name in settings.py?
Or could it be because I deleted the migration files?
I have no clue why I get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, actually, you could just simply forget to synchronize your database. If so, do it!:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

If not, maybe you'll need to completely drop database (if you have data in it) and start over again.

Comment: Thank you. I have dropped the database and recreated it. then i synced it